# Entity Framework Core - Chave Composta

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Até a versao 1.0 do EF Core eu estava tendo problemas ao fazer UPDATE em um registro do banco de dados que contivesse uma chave composta.  Se eu tentasse alterar o valor ID de um dos campos da chave composta, não era permitido e dava erro. Me orientaram nos fóruns que era um problema do EF Core que ainda não havia sido corrigido. Então, todas as minhas tabelas foram criadas com apenas uma chave primária e deixei a aplicação tratar isso... mas confesso que isso me incomoda.
Alguém sabe se isso já foi corrigido?

Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alteração de valor da chave primária é uma pratica que não é recomendada pelo Entity Framework.

Em se tratando de arquitetura de banco de dados alterar a identificação do registro é um conceito errôneo. O correto é excluir o registro e inserir um novo com uma nova identificação.

Dito isto, pela pesquisa que fiz, aparentemente o EF Core não considera isso um problema a ser corrigido por isso talvez nunca será implementado.

Bom, como eu sou um interessado no assunto, estou te respondendo aqui mais para abrir uma discussão a respeito.

Abraços.

Comment: Entendi... Obrigado pela ajuda @Thiago Araújo!!!